How can I create a zoom-in animation GIF using Python?
In this question, I created a GIF that shows the convergence of pentagons using a zoom-in animation. I used GeoGebra to graph and animate 50 pentagons.

However, zooming in on the 50th iteration resulted in significant lag and imprecise rendering, hindering further exploration. Additionally, manually coding the constructions in GeoGebra was time-consuming (over 6 hours for 50 iterations).
I am working on a general version of this question which need a lot of sequences to be drawn at once and using GeoGebra doesn't seem to be convenient.
I wrote this code that can calculate the points of the pentagon:
import math


print("Number of pentagons")
n=int(input() )
m=max(n,50)
m= min(m, 200)
from decimal import Decimal
import decimal

decimal.getcontext().prec = m
Decimal(10)**(-m)


# enter your coordinates here
A=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
B=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
C=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
D=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
E=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]

print("Enter the coordinates of A_1")
A[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
A[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))
print("Enter the coordinates of B_1")
B[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
B[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))
print("Enter the coordinates of C_1")
C[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
C[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))
print("Enter the coordinates of D_1")
D[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
D[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))
print("Enter the coordinates of E_1")
E[0]=Decimal(float (input() ))
E[1]=Decimal(float (input() ))
X=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
Y=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
Z=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
W=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]
T=[Decimal(0),Decimal(0)]

#defining some useful functions--------------------------------------------
def v(a,b):
    result= [b[0]-a[0], b[1]-a[1]]
    return result 
def crs(a, b):
    result = [-Decimal(0.5)*((Decimal(a[0]*b[1])-Decimal(a[1]*b[0])))]
    return result
def dis(a,b):
    result =[Decimal(math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2))]
    return result 




for i in range (2,n+1):
    AB= dis(A,B)[0]
    BC= dis(B,C)[0]
    CD= dis(C,D)[0]
    DE= dis(D,E)[0]
    EA= dis(E,A)[0]



    #Here to calculate A_n--------------------------------------------
    x=   CD*crs(v(D,C),v(D,E))[0]
    y=  -CD*crs(v(E,D),v(E,B))[0]+  2*DE*crs(v(C,B),v(C,D))[0]
    z=  -CD*crs(v(C,B),v(C,E))[0]+  2*BC*crs(v(D,C),v(D,E))[0]
    t=   CD*crs(v(C,B),v(C,D))[0]
    X[0]=(x *B[0]+y*C[0]+z*D[0]+t*E[0])/(x+y+z+t)
    X[1]=(x *B[1]+y*C[1]+z*D[1]+t*E[1])/(x+y+z+t)



    #Here to calculate B_n--------------------------------------------
    x=   DE*crs(v(E,D),v(E,A))[0]
    y=  -DE*crs(v(A,E),v(A,C))[0]+  2*EA*crs(v(D,C),v(D,E))[0]
    z=  -DE*crs(v(D,C),v(D,A))[0]+  2*CD*crs(v(E,D),v(E,A))[0]
    t=   DE*crs(v(D,C),v(D,E))[0]
    Y[0]=(x *C[0]+y*D[0]+z*E[0]+t*A[0])/(x+y+z+t)
    Y[1]=(x *C[1]+y*D[1]+z*E[1]+t*A[1])/(x+y+z+t)



    #Here to calculate C_n--------------------------------------------
    x=   EA*crs(v(A,E),v(A,B))[0]
    y=  -EA*crs(v(B,A),v(B,D))[0]+  2*AB*crs(v(E,D),v(E,A))[0]
    z=  -EA*crs(v(E,D),v(E,B))[0]+  2*DE*crs(v(A,E),v(A,B))[0]
    t=   EA*crs(v(E,D),v(E,A))[0]
    Z[0]=(x *D[0]+y*E[0]+z*A[0]+t*B[0])/(x+y+z+t)
    Z[1]=(x *D[1]+y*E[1]+z*A[1]+t*B[1])/(x+y+z+t)



    #Here to calculate D_n--------------------------------------------
    x=   AB*crs(v(B,A),v(B,C))[0]
    y=  -AB*crs(v(C,B),v(C,E))[0]+  2*BC*crs(v(A,E),v(A,B))[0]
    z=  -AB*crs(v(A,E),v(A,C))[0]+  2*EA*crs(v(B,A),v(B,C))[0]
    t=   AB*crs(v(A,E),v(A,B))[0]
    W[0]=(x *E[0]+y*A[0]+z*B[0]+t*C[0])/(x+y+z+t)
    W[1]=(x *E[1]+y*A[1]+z*B[1]+t*C[1])/(x+y+z+t)



    #Here to calculate E_n--------------------------------------------
    x=   BC*crs(v(C,B),v(C,D))[0]
    y=  -BC*crs(v(D,C),v(D,A))[0]+  2*CD*crs(v(B,A),v(B,C))[0]
    z=  -BC*crs(v(B,A),v(B,D))[0]+  2*AB*crs(v(C,B),v(C,D))[0]
    t=   BC*crs(v(B,A),v(B,C))[0]
    T[0]=(x *A[0]+y*B[0]+z*C[0]+t*D[0])/(x+y+z+t)
    T[1]=(x *A[1]+y*B[1]+z*C[1]+t*D[1])/(x+y+z+t)



    A=X
    B=Y
    C=Z
    D=W
    E=T
    print(f"A_{i}= {A}")
    print(f"B_{i}= {B}")
    print(f"C_{i}= {C}")
    print(f"D_{i}= {D}")
    print(f"E_{i}= {E}")
    print("\n")

I would like to create a similar zoom-in animation using Python. Since Python can calculate the points, I believe it should be possible to achieve this, but I have encountered several challenges:

Using the standard 15 decimals results in division by zero errors after 20-30 iterations so my code must use more than 15 decimal places. I solved this issue by using the Decimal library in Python, which treats values as strings, this make it impossible to graph.
I need to graph multiple polygons and there should be at least 15 different distinguishable colors that loops to avoid visual overlap. I'm not sure how to achieve this.
Assuming I can solve the above issues, I need to create a smooth zoom-in animation. The zoom in is anything put smooth so I can't just graph these pentagons and record while I zoom in.


One option would be to play with the axes limits during a FuncAnimation from matplotlib :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for p in pentagons:
    ax.plot(*p.exterior.xy)

xlim, ylim = ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim()
ax.set(xticks=[], yticks=[])

def zoomin(frame):
    sf = 2 ** (-frame / 10)  # some scaling factor
    ax.set_xlim(xlim[0] * sf, xlim[1] * sf)
    ax.set_ylim(ylim[0] * sf, ylim[1] * sf)
    ax.set_title(f"{frame=}")
    
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, zoomin, frames=len(pentagons), interval=10) # ms

NB: The animation's performance can be improved much more with blitting, if needed.

Used pentagons:
import numpy as np
from libpysal.cg import alpha_shape
from shapely import Polygon
from shapely.affinity import scale

def rnd_pent(seed=None, vertices=5):
    rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
    return alpha_shape(rng.random(size=(vertices, 2)), alpha=1).union_all()

pentagons = [
    scale(p, 2**i, 2**i)
    for i in range(1000)
    if (p := rnd_pent()).geom_type == "Polygon"
]

